# Give delay between request javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I am processing number large CSV files with 1 to 10 M rows, after processing a raw and sending the URL to a function to get details about that URL and save it in a text file. There is rate limit so I need to wait 1 minute between each request. I cannot use normal 'settimeout'  because it may affect my host memory. so I tried [bottleneck](https://github.com/SGrondin/bottleneck) npm

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  datastore: "ioredis",
  clearDatastore: false,
  maxConcurrent: 1,
  minTime: 60000,
  clientOptions: {
    host: config.api.redisHost,
    port: config.api.redisPort
  }
});
function processRequest(value) {
  console.log('value', value, new Date());
}
async function increment(counter) {
  console.log(' increment function', new Date());
  let result = await limiter.schedule(() => processRequest(counter));
}
//Feed data
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  increment(i);
}
```

Here requests are not waiting 'minTime' ie 1 minute. Am I doing anything wrong or any other way around? I am really worried about memory that's why I am using 'Redis'.

Comment: *"...I cannot use normal 'settimeout' because it may affect my host memory..."* Huh? That doesn't follow.

Comment: I am not sure about, there will be millions of records to process, will it consume more system memory?

Comment: It depends, you haven't really given enough detail in the question to answer that. But since the bottleneck lib is basically doing the same thing, I don't see it would help. If you're worried about memory, don't read data until you can also process it.

Comment: But they are saving it in redis instead of memory.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. But fundamentally, does it really make sense to read the data before you can do something with it? I think we need to understand more when/how you're reading data vs. processing it to help you.